# VLC Pulse Audio Errors in Debian Subsystem on win 10

Tags: linux, python-3.x, vlc, python-vlc

I am writing a small program in my Debian Environment on Windows 10.  I intend to use this code later on my Raspberry Pi 4.

The code runs videos through VLC at certain times of day.

The core of the VLC code (Python3) is below.  Full Python code at the bottom.

VLC code:

```
import vlc;

Instance = vlc.Instance('--fullscreen');
player = Instance.media_player_new();
Media = Instance.media_new("../videos/starscape.mp4");
Media.get_mrl();
player.set_media(Media);

player.play();
```

However, this is throwing all sorts of errors.

```
VLC media player 3.0.7 Vetinari (revision 3.0.7-0-g86cee31099)
shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
[00007fffdc1e0410] vlcpulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
[00007fffdc225830] dbus interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
[00007fffdc225830] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[00007fffdc1291a0] main libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed
[00007fffdc204440] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[00007fffdc1291a0] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[00007fffdc1291a0] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
[00007fffdc204440] skins2 interface error: cannot initialize OSFactory
```

Here is what I have tried to fix it:

1. apt-get update and apt-get upgrade
2. uninstall and reinstall vlc
3. uninstall and reinstall python-vlc
4. uninstall and reinstall pulseaudio
5. google these errors and try random solutions

I have never worked with VLC from the CLI before, so I do not know if this is an error with my code, with my install, or with the Debian instance.

Can anyone point me the right way?

FULL CODE (still WIP, but the general idea is there)
Gist: https://gist.github.com/Code2Empower/7deb6e05ffd10b0ea83eaff41c8cf294

Comment: Trying starting pulseaudio before you run your code and add ` --no-xlib` to your `vlc.Instance('--fullscreen')` instance.

Comment: Thanks, but even trying any pulseaudio commands is giving me a dbus error.  `[pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory`

Comment: If you know that you are running dbus, perhaps this might help https://www.novaspirit.com/2016/08/19/ubuntu-bash-windows-10-dbus-error-fix/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I am an idiot.  Installing Debian on Windows 10, creates a completely headless install.

So, of course VLC is giving errors.

I also stopped using `vlc-python` to make the call to vlc and used the `subprocess` module (much cleaner).

I tested the code in a Windows environment, and it works.  I will test it on the Pi, when it gets here, but it should behave the same.

Here is the new vlc code, in case anyone else needs it.

```
import subprocess;
media = "../videos/starscape.mp4";

subprocess.Popen(["vlc.exe", media, "-f", "-L" ]);
```

Gist:  https://gist.github.com/Code2Empower/7deb6e05ffd10b0ea83eaff41c8cf294